# Raw logs from the k8s pods

Tags: logging, kubernetes, syslog

I want to store the raw logs provided by the pods in stdout. Is there any better way to scrape the log and store it somewhere without using es for indexing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many ways you can achieve the same.

Refer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/

Typically a Daemonset or a Sidecar container is used